# When I parse xml with php in my wordpress site the screen only prints a 0

Tags: xml, wordpress

When I use xml in my wordpress site the screen only prints a    0
Any ideas? the page is blank with just a zero printed
Thanks (code below)

```
<?php
$xmlObject =
"<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<properties>
  <property>
    <listing-type>rental</listing-type>
    <status>for rent</status>
  </property>
</properties>";

    $data = simplexml_load_string($xmlObject) or die("Our availabilities feed is temporarily unavailable. Please try again later");
      $from = $data->property->listing-type;
      echo $from;
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

The dash is not allowed in a [label in PHP](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.basics.php). 
It will probably be interpreted as a minus. To prevent this wrap the property name in curly braces and quotes. Like this:

```
<?php
     $data = simplexml_load_string($xmlObject) or die("Our availabilities feed is temporarily unavailable. Please try again later");
          $from = $data->property->{'listing-type'};
          echo $from;
?>
```